# Ethernet-by-USB not found on new Ubuntu 15.1

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.1 running on a dual boot system with Windows 10 on the other partition.  I have the following networking equipment available:

- Broadcom wireless card installed (it's a Dell) which I do not expect to get to work until I have network access by other means
- Linksys AC1200 wireless adapter which I had hoped might work out of the box
- Belkin USB hub with ethernet port connected to my router, which I *did* expect to work right out of the box, but doesn't.  (It *does* work on the same hardware but under Windows 10.)  Note there is no ethernet port directly on the machine, hence the USB hub.

`Ifconfig -a` gives me nothing but the lo loopback interface.  I'm not sure if I should see eth0, usb0, or both, but the fact is, I see neither.  Just the lo loopback.

How can I get the ethernet-by-USB working so I can fix the other interfaces?

**UPDATE:**  Other networking/ethernet issues run through similar questions before a solution can be offered.  I am running some of the more common requests and posting their output proactively to make things easier:

Output of `lspci | grep Eth`: Nothing, no hits

Output of `lspci | grep USB`:

```
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family eSB xHCI (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family eSB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family eSB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
```

Contents of `/etc/network/interfaces':

```
# interfaces (5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Any help would be appreciated:  Without any kind of network access, this device is as useful as a boat anchor.

**UPDATE:** for anyone who gets here by searching for Dell or Broadcom, the following [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) is an excellent resource, still valid for 15.1.

Comment: If you have an android mobile phone, just connect it to your wifi and enable "usb tethering" on your computer.

Comment: This is a great idea, and it almost works.  Ubuntu seems to be continuously mounting (often failing) and unmounting the phone (Samsung Galaxy running Android 5.0.1.)  I can briefly get a network connection-- better than anything so far!-- but then it dies soon afterward.

Comment: It continuously tries, mostly failing to mount the phone with error message:  "Unable to open MTP device '[usb:001, xxx]'"  where xxx is the number of the failed attempt.

Comment: Check your wireing. Maybe your port does not provide enough power, so try another port, a usb hub or charge it before you try again.

Comment: All three ports are known to work (tested with other devices) but for some reason, using a hub seemed to do the trick.  While I am very curious about why the ethernet-through-USB failed to work and how to fix it, I have managed to get the onboard wireless working to my satisfaction.    Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any Android phone to connect to wifi on linux.

Just connect it to your wifi, connect it to your pc, and enable usb-tethering.

You might need to charge the phone before so it's not using too much power, or use an active hub with it's own power supply.

Comment: I think that comment misses the point about _not expectng the DeLL network card to work_ before having another network link (to download drivers I imagine??).  Along similar lines though; you could try the USB Wired Ethernet from the mobile phone's micro-USB .... ?

Comment: Novak, if you have any question, please ask. If not, set it as solution.